# Average of 2 registers, avoiding overflow in assembly?

Tags: assembly, average, 8051

My problem is that I don't know how to handle the addition when it gets out of the 8-Bit range.

My program runs with small Hex numbers like #02h + #05h but not with higher numbers like #0A9H + #0B5H.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 numbers, there's an asm trick: the carry flag holds the 9th bit of the ADD result, and we can right shift that 9-bit value with rotate-right through carry.  8051's  [RRC instruction](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_rrc.htm) does that.

```
   ADD A, R0
   RRC
```

---

Without that, see questions like
[How can I safely average two unsigned ints in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816446/how-can-i-safely-average-two-unsigned-ints-in-c) and [Explanation of the safe average of two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106350/explanation-of-the-safe-average-of-two-numbers)

For more than 2 numbers, do extended-precision (using add-with-carry) to keep a wider sum.

Comment: @Doomedtostudy: Not like this; you'd need a 12-bit sum to hold the largest possible result (`10 * 0xff` = 0x9f6).  You might use RRC as part of extended-precision division when you're done, though.  Since your divisor isn't even a power of 2 anymore, that part isn't just an extended-precision shift.  If you need more help with that, ask a new question where you describe what you're actually trying to do (I didn't find this answer in an existing question, so this Q&A is hopefully useful to future readers in current form). Or just use `uint16_t` in C and see what an optimizing 8051 compiler does

Comment: Well thank you mate. I will ask another question than.